# How can I add a font to a project?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I need to include the 'proxima-nova' font in the project.
I tried to find it in google fonts
but he is not there. I found it on fonts.adobe.com, but I don't know if it's possible to connect it somehow, maybe someone knows what solutions can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metropolis can also help it is most fantastic and nearly alternative to Proxima Nova.

Answer (score 1):

On google fonts "Nanum Gothic" is pretty similar to proxima-nova

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the font from Adobe you need to have an active license.
Then you would be able to download the font and add it to your project as described here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp

Comment: ok, there are options where else you can get the 'proxima-nova' font?

Comment: You can check https://befonts.com/proxima-nova-font.html

Answer (score 0):

get your fonts from [google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/), its free with tons of fonts.

#### scroll and select the font you like

[image]

#### then scroll down

[image]

#### then select the font style you like and click the little plus icon

[image]

#### once you selected all the styles you like click the icon in the top right of the page

[image]

#### use the red link code in the top of your html, and use the blue in your css

[image]

Comment: I need exactly 'proxima-nova' font, but it's not there

Comment: @Denis download proxima-nova [here](https://dl.freefontsfamily.com/download/Proxima-Nova-Font) keep a local backup of this file, incase it goes down